# Syntax Error When Importing List of Class Objects

Tags: python, list, class, syntax-error

I have a program where I want to store a list of class objects in another file. To do this i add objects to a list and then save that list to another file using this code. However, when my program tries to import the list back, it fails.
Here is my code

```
import sys
from test_two import *
print(test_list)
class Test:
   def __init__(self):
       self.number = 5
test_list = [Test(),Test(),Test()]
writing =open('test_two.py','a')
print(test_list)
writing.write("TestList = {}".format(test_list))
writing.close()
```

And Here is the Program storing the lists

```
class Test:
   def __init__(self):
       self.number = 5
TestList = [<__main__.Test object at 0x103acc690>, <__main__.Test object at 0x103ab38d0>, <__main__.Test object at 0x103b54750>]
```

However, in the original program, when i try importing i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/rudiherrig 1 2/Documents/test.py", line 2, in <module>
   from test_two import *
 File "/Users/rudiherrig 1 2/Documents/test_two.py", line 4
   TestList = [<__main__.Test object at 0x103acc690>, <__main__.Test object at 0x103ab38d0>, <__main__.Test object at 0x103b54750>]
            ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
I have tried searching stack overflow and google for errors when lists have objects in them but could not find anything. Is that even the problem?, I am pretty sure lists can store objects but am not sure. Basically, What do you think is causing the problem?

Comment: Lists can store objects.  The information you have written to the file is not nearly enough to reconstruct those objects, much less use valid syntax for representing them.  You might want to look into something like `pickle`.

Comment: `<__main__.Test object at 0x103acc690>` is the default string representation of an instance of a class that does not define `__str__()` or `__repr__()`.  It is *absolutely not* anything you can actually write in Python source code!

Comment: How would you recommend storing a lot of of objects in one 'list', without using lists? I have looked into the pickle module but it seems like it can only store one value at a  time.

Answer (score 1):

1. I noticed the variable names `test_list` and `TestList` may refer to the same list, if you change `TestList` to `test_list` in your class fine, the error should disappear?
2. Also, if test_list were a list of strings:

`test_list = ['<__main__.Test object at 0x103acc690>', '<__main__.Test object at 0x103ab38d0>', '<__main__.Test object at 0x103b54750>']`

the code runs fine, creates test_two.py with these content:

`TestList = [<__main__.Test object at 0x000001EE35510588>, <__main__.Test object at 0x000001EE35510508>, <__main__.Test object at 0x000001EE355105C8>]`

and prints the same to terminal